# How do you fill a variable with an empty space in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am extracting the metadata of audio files to create full Titles.
When I extract the metadata of a file, sometimes there are fields that are not filled up, thus returning a variable that is `None`.

How can I fill a variable with a whitespace so it is not `None` and it just shows a whitespace on the final title ?

```
if key.startswith("genre"):
    genre = value[0]
      if genre == None:
          genre = ''
```

Comment: could you please give an example of your data format or code?

Comment: Do you use Python 2 or python 3?

Comment: See `str.format()`  https://pyformat.info

Comment: `if not title: title = ' '`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the value, use this:

```
if title is None:
    title= ''
```

In this way, it will not be None. It will be a blank string.

Comment: Check my edited code, that  is what I was doing and It still returns ```None```

Comment: because you need to write it to your dictionary. Instead of genre = None make your_dict[key] = None

Answer (score 0):

First check if `title` is `None`, if it is assign an empty string.

```
if not title:
    title = ''
```

Comment: Check the dit to see my code, that is what I was doing before asking.

Comment: @xavier Then `title` isn't `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> t = None
>>> print (t)
None
>>> if t == None: t = " "
... 
>>> print (t)

>>> print (len(t))
1
```

Note " " not ""

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that '==' is not the way to see if it is None. Thanks.